# How to store the result of a templatetag using Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

Working with Django 1.5.5 I need to call a custom templatetag and somehow store the result in a variable, to check if it contains a non empty empty string. I need something that should look like:

```
{% load smart_html %}
{% render_html widget.content as widget_content %}
{% if widget_content %}
  Do stuff here...
{% endif %}
```

This is inspired on the {% url %} built-in templatetag that allows calling it storing the result in a variable using the syntax:

```
{% url 'named_url' as my_named_url %}
```

My templatetag looks like:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_html(context, html):
    """Allows executing 'Django code' within the HTML"""
    return Template(html).render(context)
```

I also thought about adding the returned value from the custom templatetag to the context. What do you think about this? Would this be dangerous? This would look like:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_html(context, html, var_name=None):
    """Allows executing 'Django code' within the HTML"""
    html = Template(html).render(context)
    if var_name:
        context[var_name] = html
        html = ''
    return html
```

Answer (score 2):

If the tag is something you control, then perhaps consider using an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags). If the tag isn't something you control, then you might have to wrap it with an assignment tag of your own.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! This seems what I need. However, I also need the `as foo` to be optional, as it is on the `{% url %}` templatetag. I've updated my question with the modified templatetag assigning the value to the context, only if `var_name` is set. Do you have any ideas on how to do this using `assignment tag`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_html(context, content):
    return Template(content).render(context)
```

But I don't know what you are trying to achieve? Isn't it better to do this kind of stuff in your view function and based on the result call different templates with `TemplateResponse`?